# REGEX: To extract particular string from path

Tags: regex, rex

I am looking to extract particular string from path.

For example, I have to extract 4th value separated by (.) from filename. which is "lm" in below examples.

Examples:

```
/apps/java/logs/abc.defgh.ijk.lm.nopqrst.uvw.xyz.log
/apps2/java/logs/abc.defgh.ijk.lm.log
```

This will extract full file name:

```
.*\/(?<name>.*).log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.*\/(?:[^.\/]*\.){3}(?<value>[^.\/]*)[^\/]*$
```

Or, if `.log` must be the extension:

```js
.*\/(?:[^.\/]*\.){3}(?<value>[^.\/]*)[^\/]*\.log$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NwIMkU/2/). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(?:[^.\/]*\.){3}` - three occurrences of zero or more chars other than `.` and `/` as many as possible and a dot
- `(?<value>[^.\/]*)` - Group "value": zero or more chars other than `.` and `/` as many as possible
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.log` - a `.log` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
\/(?:\w+\.){3}(\w+)
```

Or

```
\/(?:\w+\.){3}(\w+).*\.log
```

Where:

- `\/` - Match string starting from `"/"`
- `(?:\w+\.){3}` - Matches 3 occurrences of `"xyz."` e.g. `abc.defgh.ijk.`
- `(\w+)` - Capture the alpanumeric string. This will contain the target value e.g. `"lm"`
- `.*\.log` - Optional. Match any set of characters that ends with `.log` e.g. `.nopqrst.uvw.xyz.log`